# How much memory allocate each line of code?

Tags: c, memory

```
char *str1 = "warning";
char str[] = "warning";
char str3[] = {'c', 'a', 't'};
char *str4[] = {"warning", "program"};
char *str5[2][20] = {"waring", "program"};
```

In my opinion second line of code should allocate 8 bytes of memory, but correct answer is 16bytes. Why?

Comment: How do you know much memory it allocates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "allocate"; none of these methods do any dynamic heap-based allocation in the sense of `malloc()`.

If you mean, "how much space is reserved on the stack", then the answer for the second line could well be 8, but **it depends on your platform and compiler**.  The compiler may decide to align all stack variables to 16-byte boundaries, for instance.

Of course, at least 8 bytes of static program space will also be required to store the string literal `"warning"` in order to initialise `str`.  The compiler may be intelligent enough to spot that you're using the same string literal in multiple places, or it may not.  Again, **it depends**.

About the only thing that doesn't depend on the compiler is the fact that `sizeof(str)` should always be `8`.

Comment: It's not clear whether these are auto (stack) variables or global... this also would make a difference since the initialization of str[] would be done at run-time (requiring memory for initialization code) if on the stack, while initialization would be performed at compile-time if global.

Comment: Sir, size of char is always 8bits irrespective of the machine we use. So, how would the "space in stack" of str[] would depend on platform or compiler..its only for integers i guess..

Comment: @Shashi: Actually, the standard only says that a `char` must be *at least* 8 bits.  But that's irrelevant.  The compiler is free to arrange the stack in any way it likes, if it thinks it will help performance.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean?

```
$ cat mem.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "warning";
    printf("%li\n", sizeof(str));
}

$ gcc mem.c 
$ ./a.out 
8
```